# Error finalizing type visitor [io.micronaut.openapi.visitor.OpenApiApplicationVisitor@16993f50]: null Mirconaut

Tags: java, gradle, micronaut

I have a gradle project with below dependencies

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id "com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin" version "2.1.5"
}
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = GROUP
            artifactId = 'common'
            version = VERSION
            from components.java
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:${micronautVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation:${micronautVersion}"
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.security:micronaut-security-annotations")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation:${micronautVersion}")

    api('io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.2.8')
    implementation 'org.mongodb:bson:4.8.1'
    api 'io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-model:3.9.4'

    api "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation:${micronautVersion}"
    api ('io.micronaut.reactor:micronaut-reactor:2.5.0')
    api('io.micronaut.security:micronaut-security-jwt:3.9.1')

}
```

Perform the below action, using the Gradle task

1. Clean
2. Build
3. PublishToMavenLocal

In the other micronaut project (using micronaut version - 3.8.2), I have included this library below

```
    plugins {
        id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
        id("io.micronaut.application") version "3.7.0"
        id "com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin" version "2.1.5"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
      ......
      implementation("fete.bird:common:0.0.0")
    }
```

When I build the application, getting the below exception as

```
error: Error finalizing type visitor [io.micronaut.openapi.visitor.OpenApiApplicationVisitor@5a03f688]: null
```

An closed bug https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1362

As suggested to remove the `mavenLocal()`, I can't remove it because using the other library from local. Since the library is in buggy face, still can't publish.

However, reversing the version to `micronautVersion=3.7.5` everythings works

Comment: I have the same problem, however I don't use mavenLocal() but a custom maven repository

Comment: problem fixed upgrading to micronaut-openapi 4.8.2 released today

Comment: @HelLViS69 Any idea which version of Micronaut will include this version of Open Api ?